# C++ ListView not working

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I have tried making my own ListView using the WinApi but all I get all these errors when trying to build
`1>client_application\main.cpp(156): error C2065: 'WC_LISTVIEW' : undeclared identifier
1>client_application\main.cpp(156): error C2065: 'LVS_REPORT' : undeclared identifier
1>client_application\main.cpp(156): error C2065: 'LVS_EDITLABELS' : undeclared identifier
1>client_application\main.cpp(156): error C2660: 'CreateWindowExA' : function does not take 11 arguments
1>client_application\main.cpp(158): error C3861: 'ListView_InsertColumn': identifier not found`

The code I have added to the file that makes it stop working is

```
HWND list = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, 
              L"",
              WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
              0, 0,
              250,
              250,
              hwnd,
              (HMENU) NULL,
              NULL,
              NULL
        );

        ListView_InsertColumn(list, 0, "Test");
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Fixed above but I now get this error

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'HWND CreateWindowExA(DWORD,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,int,int,int,int,HWND,HMENU,HINSTANCE,LPVOID)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'const wchar_t [1]' to 'LPCSTR' C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\client_application\main.cpp
```

Comment: Beyond failing to include `<CommCtrl.h>`, you are doing something else wrong: you've forgotten to define `UNICODE` in your project (or call `CreateWindowW` explicitly).

Comment: remove the L before ""

Comment: I have no errors now but it doesn't do anything, is there something else I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A quick search determined that you need to add `#include <CommCtrl.h>`, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739(v=vs.85).aspx) (see bottom of the page).

EDIT:

For your other problem, you are passing a `wchar_t*` where a `char*` is expected. 
Winapi functions like `CreateWindowEx()` are actually macros to two different functions, `CreateWindowExA()` and `CreateWindowExW()`, where the first requires a `char*` and the latter a `wchar_t*`. Either:

1. put `#define UNICODE` at the top of your file so the `CreateWindowEx()` macro resolves to the `CreateWindowExW()` function
2. call the `CreateWindowExW()` function directly.
3. change your second argument from `L""` to `TEXT("")` to match what the `CreateWindowsEx()` macro expects, which is a `TCHAR*`.

Also, do not forget to add `WS_VISIBLE`. Otherwise your control is hidden by default.

Comment: I've done everything you've said but it doesn't do anything, I get no errors when building it also.

Comment: The window is hidden by default. Add WS_VISIBLE to make it appear.